# Way to Lexicographic order for Dictionary Key/value pairs?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

I'm trying to order my HeaderParams for OAuth signature base creation.

The OAuth docs state this for ordering them:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1.3.2

The parameters are sorted by name, using ascending byte value ordering.  If two or more parameters share the same name, they are sorted by their value.

So if I have a C# **dictionary** of header param pairs like this, how can I sort this for OAuth?

UPDATED:

I believe doing a parameterList.Keys.ToList().Sort(); "should" accomplish what I need as far as sorting this dictionary in ascending order based on Key (Key Name).

But it's not working, I see the params out of order still after it hits my sort here:

```
oauth_consumer_key, H64HgpIU3bdA4M  
oauth_token, rbh4gd0S5GfAXEAF2X 
oauth_signature_method, HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp, 1330534605
oauth_nonce, 4207386
```

it should be:

```
oauth_consumer_key, H64HgpIU3bdA4M  
oauth_nonce, 4207386
oauth_signature_method, HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp, 1330534605
oauth_token, rbh4gd0S5GfAXEAF2X
```

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary can't be sorted.

However, you can access the keys in a sorted way:

```
IDictionary<string, string> values = //...
var sorted = values.OrderByAscending(kvp => kvp.Key)
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sorted)
    //...
```

Alternatively, you can order by the KeyValuePair directly and pass a custom IComparer

Comment: what did you mean by foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sorted)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort a dictionary by key you should use a SortedDictionary. Anyway since you could have the same name you'd better use a List like this:

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b5", "%3D%253D"));
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a3", "a")); 
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a3", "%3D%253D"));
    list.Sort(Compare);

    static int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, string> a, KeyValuePair<string, string> b)      {
       if (a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key) == 0) {
            return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value);
        }
        return a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key);
    }
```

Comment: I also don't know if this sort is meeting the sort requirements in OAuth.  It's hard to tell which is part of the problem is creating the sort in the first place.